# Firebase added/removed/changed children listener using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The official [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/query.html#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_query_1a71e2af7868312246b5da3024bb13204c) states:

**ChildAdded**

> EventHandler< ChildChangedEventArgs > ChildAdded
>
> Event raised when children nodes are added relative to this location.
>
> Register a handler to observe when children are added relative to this
>   Query object. Each time time children nodes are added, your handler
>   will be called with an immutable snapshot of the data.

**ChildRemoved**

> EventHandler< ChildChangedEventArgs > ChildRemoved
>
> Event raised when children nodes are removed relative to this
>   location.
>
> Register a handler to observe when children are removed relative to
>   this Query object. Each time time children nodes are removed, your
>   handler will be called with an immutable snapshot of the data.

**ChildChanged**

> EventHandler< ChildChangedEventArgs > ChildChanged
>
> Event raised when children nodes are changed relative to this
>   location.
>
> Register a handler to observe changes to children relative to this
>   Query object. Each time time children nodes are changed, your handler
>   will be called with an immutable snapshot of the data.

So far I am using ChildRemoved and ChildAdded successfully, and they work solidly and with no hassle for what I am doing. In particular, these two listeners are independent, that is to say: the actions that make one of them fire are guaranteed not make the other one fire. So, I do not have to do any synchronization or scheduling to resolve conflicts.

My question is: Are these three listener types independent of each other?

That is to say:

1. For any given action, I am guaranteed that one, and at most one, of the three listeners will fire.
2. Only ChildAdded fires when the listener is first established. The other two listener types do not.

A note about the documentation, it would resolved ambiguity if the documentation for the ChildChanged would specify what it means by "childChanged": does it include addition/removal/moving/editing of a child, or does it only focus on editing to an existing child?

Answer (score 0):

Each one of these events is a specific way to handle synchronization of data across clients.

> - #### .childChanged
>
>   will be called whenever something changes

So if you have a real time database like the following:

```
/store/<random-number-inserted-by-firebase-1>/name/store-1
/store/<random-number-inserted-by-firebase-1>/location/street-1
/store/<random-number-inserted-by-firebase-1>/items/0/name/name-1
/store/<random-number-inserted-by-firebase-1>/items/0/type/type-1
/store/<random-number-inserted-by-firebase-1>/items/1/name/name-2
/store/<random-number-inserted-by-firebase-1>/items/1/type/type-2
/store/<random-number-inserted-by-firebase-2>/name/store-2
/store/<random-number-inserted-by-firebase-2>/location/street-2
```

You start the childAdded, childChanged, and childRemoved observers on "/store" together.

If you change `/store/<random-number-inserted-by-firebase-1>/items/0/type/type-1` to `/store/<random-number-inserted-by-firebase-1>/items/0/type/new-type-1` your childChanged callback function will receive a dictionary `["random-number-inserted-by-firebase-1": ["name": "store-1", "location": "street-1", "items": [["name": "name-1", "type": "new-type-1"], ["name": "name-2", "type": "type-2"]]` **.childAdded** listens for anything that changes in a node.